# Load different content inside same <section> based on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

Basically, intead of having multiple html files and reload whole site, I'd like to just load the relevant  IDs I want from other files (they all have the same exact structure, just different content showing different images/different description) based on what category button the user clicks on the navigation bar.

Is this hard to do with JQuery, are there better solutions than the one I thought?

Comment: look into the jquery load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Ok, that works. But now, I replace some HTML code inside the <section> i want and my problem is that on this HTML code I have to run a js file that modifies it based on the device. Normally I load site -> js file runs. But since i inject some code at a later time, I need to rerun this js file in ashyncrhonous way using ajax. How can I rerun that js file after I replaced the portion of code I want?

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted some code here but what you're probably looking to do is pass a call back function to load https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp. And if you actually do need to reload a script look into jquery getscript https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/